# How to use ESRI 'Ecological Land Units' in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, layer-file

I am trying to use the Map of Global Ecological Land Units –
An Ecophysiographic Stratification Approach (2014) in QGIS. I downloaded the World ELU 2015.zip from
https://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/ecosystems/Global/

I am able to add the tif to the map and partially visualize the ELU with the default style classification QGIS (2.18.8) using grayscale pseudocolor.

ESRI has published a white paper with guidelines on on how to use the ELU on desktop but of course the explanation is ArcGIS and ArcGIS online based.  https://blogs.esri.com/esri/esri-insider/2016/04/06/updated-map-features-global-ecology-in-unprecedented-detail/

I never used raster data before.

So my question is on how can I:
1)obtain the information of dataset in QGIS (beyond just the image and pixel values by clicking on it), and 
2)bring the ELU-ESRI color scheme to my QGIS map project

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191258/global-shapefile-of-biomes-ecoregions/216917#216917